# Why use hair instead of emitter as particles?

Tags: particles

So I was watching Blender Guru's Donut tutorial and for the sprinkles on top of the donut he uses hair and not emitter as a particle. Why does he do that? What is the difference between hair and emitter?

Here is the video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNmnPXY9UQA&list=PLjEaoINr3zgEq0u2MzVgAaHEBt--xLB6U&t=0s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the `Hair` particle then a fixed number of particles will be created and their number and position won't change over time as your animation plays. So this is good for hair, sprinkles, or grass.

If you use the `Emitter`, the number of partciles will change over time. So if you play your animation, you'll see the object starts emitting particles that move away from your object and then disappear. You would use an emitter more for water, smoke, or sparks.

For demonstration, look at how the emitters of these 2 cubes change while the animation is playing. The one on the left uses `Hair`, the one on the right uses `Emitter`.

[image]